# Flexbox - Grow label relative to field using flex-grow, shrink, basis

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a long label with no spaces in a div. See the screenshot. The label can grow or shrink based on localization. I want the label to grow to as much space as it needs, pushing the field to be smaller. The field div needs to have a flex-basis of 60% to confirm to other fields above and below it, though it should shrink if the label needs to grow.  Currently there is an overlap, like in the screenshot (or is cut off if I apply overflow: hidden to the label's div).

I have tried tinkering with various values for flex-grow and flex-shrink to no avail. I don't think those attributes are what I need to accomplish this but not sure.

HTML:

```
<div class="class-flex">
    <div class="label-column">
        I'mALongLabelWithNoSpaces:
    </div>
    <div class="field-column">
        <!-- input field which should shrink goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.label-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 40%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 5px;
}

.field-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 60%;
    padding: 3px 7px 3px 5px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: also, `flex-basis != width`

Comment: I need to have the flex-basis: 60% for conformity with other label/field pairs, not shown in the screenshot (and just generally so the field will be the desired width when the label is short). I could get rid of the flex-basis: 40% on label-column.

Comment: If the text exceeds 40%, it should grow to as much space as it needs, with the field shrinking to accommodate this accordingly.

Comment: Sorry. It is OK if the left side of the field does not align with the fields above and below it in the case where the label needs to grow. But when the label is sufficiently small, the field should align with those above and below it as normal.

Comment: Here you go....answered below.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use `flex-basis` of 60% on the input div but allow it to shrink using `flex-shrink:1` but not to grow by setting `flex-grow:0`.

This can be set using a single property of `flex: 0 1 60%;`

then we set the input to be 100% wide...and separate the two divs using `justify-content:space-between`.

Thus the label div has no set width and expands as required, the input div starts at 60% but can only get smaller.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.class-flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1em auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.label-column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 0 3px 5px;
}

.field-column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 60%;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-flex">
  <div class="label-column">
    I'mALongLabelWithNoSpaces:
  </div>
  <div class="field-column">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class-flex">
  <div class="label-column">
    Label:
  </div>
  <div class="field-column">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK thank you. Will this solution only work with a fixed px width in .class-flex? My .class-flex is on an element which needs to be able to resize with the screen.